# With opensles do you need a seperate audio player for each mp3 you want to play simultaneously?

Tags: android, c++, audio, decode, opensl

I have seen how the output-mix can be shared between players but I am wondering how you would play multiple mp3 files simultaneously without using multiple players.

Obviously I could decode the mp3s with a 3rd party library (e.g. ffmpeg) and then mix the buffer streams myself and pass into a player but this about over the top for my needs.
Decoding with opensles seems to require a FD/URI->BufferQueue player object so that would not change the number of players.

Are there techniques I am missing?
The only limitations are that the solution must use c++ and opensles.